# Правильная организация повторного использования исходников в нескольких проектах MSVS

Tags: visual-studio-2019

есть исходники, которые используются в нескольких проектах, постоянно их подключать довольно утомительно. Есть ли инструмент в MSVS по типу как сделано в QT в виде подпроектов, т.е неких файлов в которых прописаны используемые h/cpp. Это дает возможность подключить в проект только этот файл и все. Т.е есть sln в котором находится два проекта, нужно в третьем использовать cpp которые используются в двух других. Там они просто ручками добавлены.